# Disable or Remove 'Uninstall', 'Force Stop' button in Application manager in Device Settings

Tags: android, device-admin

In Android, I developed service and install apk on device.

I need disable or hide 'uninstall' button in Application Manager Setting, also 'Force Stop' button.
In Application Manager Setting, there are some services and apps exist like above.

I also have seen Device administration api on [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin).

I'd appreciate it if someone would teach me.

Comment: This is not possible, unless your device is rooted

Comment: @HB. developed service is for normal device user. Is there any method for non-rooting devices?

Comment: `Is there any method for non-rooting devices?` No. Why would Google allow this? You are trying to force users to not be able to uninstall your application or stop your application. Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Answer, lock your settings. You can't "force stop" apps with settings locked.